# Laravel Model Get Method Decoding JSON

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hi there below is what I'm storing in my db but when I use my get method in my model I have to use json_decode twice when formating my data why is this happening and can I have it just use it once somehow.

json exactly in db:

```
"[{\"id\":\"1\",\"country\":\"New Zealand\",\"shipping_rate\":\"1\"},{\"id\":\"2\",\"country\":\"Australia\",\"shipping_rate\":\"2\"}]"
```

Model Get Method:

```
public function getshippingAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['shipping'] ? json_decode(json_decode($this->attributes['shipping'])) : [];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not clear enough from your question but the [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) offers a builtin mechanism for attribute casting (Since [v-5.1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)). In this case, in your model, just declare a `$casts` property for example:

```php
protected $casts = [
    'shipping' => 'array',
    // more ...
];
```

Because of the `$casts` property given above, whenever you'll write (create/update) a model, you don't need to explicitly use `json_encode` to convert the array to `json` string, `Laravel` will do it for you and also, when you'll retrieve the model (single/collection), the `shipping` attribute will be automatically converted back to an `array` so you don't need to use `json_decode` for working with the attribute.

Regarding the response, that will be also handled by laravel if you don't convert it to `json` manually (when returning a `model/collection`). This will possibly solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getshippingAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['shipping'] ? json_decode($this->attributes['shipping']) : [];
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Answer (score -1):

Try return json response

```
public function getshippingAttribute()
{
    return response()->json($this->attributes['shipping'])
}
```

Comment: If I do that I get an empty object that only contains headers attribute for an ajax call so this option will not work because I'm not making a database call there I'm formatting the output of a field

Comment: in the documentation of laravel they say :
The json method will automatically set the Content-Type header to application/json, as well as convert the given array to JSON using the json_encode PHP function:

Comment: maybe the variable is null